# Segue lag, tableview in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am working at my first application in Swift 3. I am using tableView (by "extension MainController: UITableViewDataSource"). And from this tableView, by storyboard I have two segues. One for editing (by clicking on accessory icon) and the second one for more detail screen (by clicking on a table row). I am not calling this segues by code, but by storyboard.

And my problem is that there is sometimes huge lag. Like after clicking on a row, the next screen is showing after 30 seconds. But now always. Sometimes its working immediately. Interesting thing is that when I touch row 1, and nothing happens, next I am clicking row 2 and then row 1 is appearing.

I am also using delegates, this is the code for preparing segues:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // 1
    if segue.identifier == "AddSensor" {
        // 2
        let navigationController = segue.destination
            as! UINavigationController
        // 3
        let controller = navigationController.topViewController
            as! AddController
        // 4
        controller.delegate = self
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "EditSensor" {
        let navigationController = segue.destination
            as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationController.topViewController
            as! AddController
        controller.delegate = self
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(
            for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {
            controller.sensorToEdit = sensors[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "DetailSeq" {
        let navigationController = segue.destination
            as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationController.topViewController
            as! DetailController
        controller.delegate = self
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(
            for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {
            controller.sensorRecieved = sensors[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

}
```

I was reading that it was common bug in iOS8 and could be resolved by adding

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {  
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailSeq",sender: self)
}
}
```

But it didn't worked for me. I don't know what should I do next to resolve this problem. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Did you have this working *without* lag, and then started seeing the lag? If so, what did you change? If you never had it working to begin with, you might want to start small and go step-by-step... Just try segueing to plain view controllers - no delegates, no passing data, etc. Once you get that working, then start adding in the other parts.

Comment: It is called a Segue, not a Seque. G, no Q.

Comment: This might be worth checking. Can you make sure that you have implemented "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and not "didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath"  emphasis on "Deselect", there have been instances in the past where I implemented did "DeSelect" and this will cause the segue to trigger only on deselect. Also, can you post more code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823544/ios-segue-freeze-for-many-seconds-before-showing-new-view), you may be able to fix your bug if you present your view controller in code rather than with the segue in the storyboard. Something like this, where your destination is the VC that you want to go to.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: 
    NSIndexPath) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.presentViewController(destination, animated: true) { () -> Void                    
              in

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailSeq",sender: self)
    }
}
```